# Real Gases vs Ideal Gases

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws

Real gases behave less ideally at low temperatures because intermolecular forces have a greater effect.

But wouldn't they still be non-ideal at high temperature? Even though they overcome the intermolecular forces, they aren't moving with their normal energy. Doesn't that make them non-ideal, because the pressure is greater than it would be in an ideal gas?

Comment: Well, that's right: at higher T they are closer to ideal, but not quite there yet.

Comment: "because the pressure is greater than it would be in an ideal gas? " What do you believe is the pressure of an ideal gas?

Answer (score 1):

Low pressure and high temperature are the necessary condition for ideal behavior of real gases. So if temperature is high but pressure is not very low then the gas will show non-ideal behavior.